# Is there a way to force ssl on certain pages

Tags: security, ssl, page-specific-settings, https

I want to force a secure connection on some of my pages (ones with forms), but I don't want the whole site to work with ssl (slows it down)

Is there a way to configure specific pages to require ssl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the admin-ssl plugin. For stuff outside of wp, use rewriite rule in apache

Comment: Admin SSL plugin url: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/admin-ssl-secure-admin/

Comment: It should be noted this plugin does not work with Wordpress 3.0+

Comment: Even if it was not updated recently, WordPress HTTPS plugin works well with newer versions of WP.

Answer (score 11):

New workflow, since the Admin SSL plugin is not supported.

- use the Plugin [WP https](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-https/)
- See the settings
- If you want SSL for `wp-admin`, add this to the `wp-config.php`:

  ```
  define( 'FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', TRUE );
  ```
- If you want also SSL for the log in page, add this to the `wp-config.php`

  ```
  define( 'FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', TRUE );
  ```
- Add the follow line to the `.htaccess`; remove the default of WP

  ```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
     RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
  </IfModule>
  ```
- If you set a specific page/post to SSL in front-end, then use the following plugin or set the option in the editor of the post/page; only if you have active this possibility of the plugin WP https. see also [Gist 4081291](https://gist.github.com/4081291) for a sample plugin

  ```
  /**
   * Plugin Name: Force SSL for specific pages
   * Description: 
   * Author:      Frank Bültge
   * Author URI:  http://bueltge.de/
   * Version:     1.0.0
   */

  ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) and exit;

  if ( ! function_exists( 'fb_force_ssl' ) ) {

      add_filter( 'force_ssl' , 'fb_force_ssl', 1, 3 );
      function fb_force_ssl( $force_ssl, $id = 0, $utrl = '' ) {
          // A list of posts/page that should be SSL
          $ssl_posts = array( 22, 312 );

          if ( in_array( $id, $ssl_posts ) )
              $force_ssl = TRUE;

          return $force_ssl;
      }

  } // end if func exists
  ```
- Without Plugin WordPress HTTPS

  ```
  add_action( 'template_redirect', 'fb_ssl_template_redirect', 1 );
  function fb_ssl_template_redirect() {

          if ( is_page( 123 ) && ! is_ssl() ) {

              if ( 0 === strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'http') ) {
                  wp_redirect(preg_replace('|^http://|', 'https://', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), 301 );
                  exit();
              } else {
                  wp_redirect('https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 301 );
                  exit();
              }
          } else if ( !is_page( 123 ) && is_ssl() && !is_admin() ) {

              if ( 0 === strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'http') ) {
                  wp_redirect(preg_replace('|^https://|', 'http://', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), 301 );
                  exit();
              } else {
                  wp_redirect('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 301 );
                  exit();
              }
          }
  }
  ```

or a smaller version, but not with fallbacks, if the url is wrong

```
add_filter( 'pre_post_link', 'fb_set_ssl_url', 10, 3 );
function fb_set_ssl_url( $permalink, $post, $leavename ) {

    if ( 123 == $post->ID )
        return preg_replace( '|^http://|', 'https://', $permalink );

    return $permalink;
}
```

Comment: Merci; was not possible for me to formatted the code :(

Comment: If you're doing force ssl for admin, you don't need `define( 'FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', TRUE );`

Answer (score 4):

For WordPress version 3.0 and above, the admin-ssl plugin does not work. In order to get SSL to work, you need to take two steps:

1. Enable the Administration Over SSL option in your wp-config.php file ([see here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Over_SSL)).
2. Install the [WPSSL](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wpssl/) plugin on the site. (updated for WordPress 3.0+)
3. On the pages you want to to run over SSL, add a meta tag called "force_ssl" and set the value to "true".

You should be all set after that.

Comment: WPSSL hasn't been updated in over 2 years. Are you currently using it with an updated install of WP?

Comment: I have not, since I'm no longer working on that particular project. It might be time to find a newer plugin and recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Better WP Security](http://bit51.com/software/better-wp-security/) Plugin.  Along with a bunch of helpful tweaks to secure your site, it has some settings that allow you to force ssl to the login page, or the entire back-end if you choose, and to selected pages on the front end per content via a selection box added to the visual editor.  Very easy to use.

Of course, you do have to have SSL set-up on your server first, meaning you either have to install a self-signed certificate (not recommended) or pay for a certificate from a 3rd party authority and install it on your server.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question: "specific" pages.

Answer (score 1):

I had multiple problems with your solutions (but it helped me). I'll put my solutions here for the following case :

- Wordpress multisite
- Server on vestacp running on apache with nginx proxy

.First i only used this WP extension : "SSL Insecure Content Fixer" who can handle WPMU, and the "mixed content" error (Since "Wordpress Https" is deprecated and not working for me)

.Secondely, the is_ssl() function wasn't working with nginx proxy so i used this one :

```
function isSecure() {
  return
    (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off')
    || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443;
}
```

.Also "is_page()" wasn't working so this is my final code (for redirecting the specific pages" to https)

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'fb_ssl_template_redirect', 1 );
function fb_ssl_template_redirect() {

    global $post;

    //login = 8886
    //Pages clients
    $array_posts_ssl = array(8886);
    $array_posts_ssl_parents = array(8886);

    if ( in_array($post->ID,$array_posts_ssl)  ) {

        if ( !isSecure() ) {
            wp_redirect('https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 301 );
            exit();
        }

    } else  {

        if ( isSecure() ){
            wp_redirect('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] , 301 );
            exit();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of the plugins mentioned above seem to be outdated or at least haven't been maintained ina  while. The [WordPress-https plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-https/) seems to be the best option and will force ssl on the entire site or just on certain pages.

Comment: this plugin is really flaky for me. i hope to find a better one.

Comment: I used it one one site without any problems, but have not tested it extensively. I just don't trust using the plugins that haven't been updated in over a year. Also this developer seems pretty responsive to questions.

Answer (score 0):

Below would be the best "WordPress" way to do it, i have fully commented it for you to explain what its doing.

```
add_action('wp','_my_custom_ssl_redirect'); // the 'wp' hook is the first place the post id is set.
function _my_custom_ssl_redirect(){
    global $post,$wp; // get some global values.

    $page_ids = array(2,123,321,456); // array of page ids we want to force to ssl.

    if( is_page() && isset($post->ID) && in_array($post->ID,$page_ids) ){ // check we are on a page and its a page we want to redirect.

        wp_safe_redirect( // make sure we only redirect to "internal" urls.
            add_query_arg( // add any url query arguments back to the url.
                $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], // The current query args.
                '',
                trailingslashit( // add a trailing slash to the home url as sometimes it is not added.
                    home_url( $wp->request, "https" ), // get the home url HTTPS link.
                    301 // set the redirect to be 301 "permanent", you can use 302 "temporary" here instead.
                )
            )
        );
        exit; // exit ASAP, no point in loading anything more.
    }
}
```

Non commented version for neatness :) (same exact code)

```
add_action('wp','_my_custom_ssl_redirect');
function _my_custom_ssl_redirect(){
    global $post,$wp;

    $page_ids = array(2,123,321,456); // array of page ids we want to force to ssl.

    if( is_page() && isset($post->ID) && in_array($post->ID,$page_ids) ){ 
        wp_safe_redirect( add_query_arg( $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], '',trailingslashit(home_url( $wp->request, "https" ), 301 )) );
        exit;
    }
}
```