# How to force non SSL on just one page?

Tags: ssl

How do I force only one page on my WordPress blog to NOT use SSL?

Comment: How are you forcing the use of SSL on your site? you could make an exception for this one page..

Comment: Hi Samuel
I just installed automatically from my host. Should I probably ask my host to do it?

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/129/is-there-a-way-to-force-ssl-on-certain-pages/72803#72803) helps you. Is it the contrary, but maybe it give you an idea to change this to your requirements.